# How to make a custom EditText tool bar?

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-editor

I am currently trying to make a Writing program.  I would like the functionality of an Edit tool bar that contains things such as BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE, etc.  I see that it is under Typeface but I'm struggling to figure out how to make it function on just selected text or just for formatting text. I already have the GUI and button listeners in place.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing really built into Android for this, except at a fairly low level. I have the beginnings of a [`RichEditText` custom widget](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit), as a drop-in `EditText` replacement, but it needs a fair bit of work, which I will get to later in June (I hope I hope I hope).

In a nutshell, you will need to get a `Spannable` object from your `EditText` via `getText()`, then call methods like `setSpan()` on it to apply your formatting.

Comment: Ok I'll look deeper into Spannables.  I didn't know what they were yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Two words my friend, "creative commons".  In my experience, mundane pieces of code like date/time pickers, RTF text boxes, etc.. they've all been coded and thought through more thoroughly than you'll ever have the time for.  For something like this, don't reinvent the wheel,  check out someone else's code, build on it, and check it back in.

Comment: I have attempted that but I haven't found any code that resembles what I'm trying to do.  I'm also trying to learn and figure it out myself.  Understanding code is half the fun :)